# How to set a set interval on console data logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, setinterval

I wish to create a set interval of x milliseconds in the console logging of data. Any ideas on the code I will need to do this? Here is my code:

```
// API 
var apiUrl              =   'http://theurl.com';

// AJAX
jQuery.ajax ({
    url: apiUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        // COORDINATES
        var coordLat            =   data.coord.lat;
        var coordLng            =   data.coord.lon;
```

Comment: More than likely, you really don't want to use `setInterval`. Just do the logs when you get the data. Why log it again and again?

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to create a set interval of x milliseconds in the console logging of data.

If you wish to set an interval when logging data to the console,
you should neither need to use Ajax nor jQuery.

Instead, you can achieve this with a single line of javascript, using the `setInterval` method.

The example below logs a message to the console every `900` milliseconds.

**Working Example:**

```js
let myInterval = setInterval(() => console.log('Logging...'), 900);
```

Comment: Would this work? setInterval(()=>console.log(data), 900);

Comment: Yes, that line of javascript will log the value of the variable `data` to the console, every 900 milliseconds. The advantage of assigning the `setInterval()` statement to a variable is that it allows you to subsequently invoke `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think you want to update data periodically.

So this is an example based on your code:

```
        function getCoordinates()
        {
        // API 
        var apiUrl              =   'http://theurl.com';

        // AJAX
        jQuery.ajax ({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                // COORDINATES
                var coordLat            =   data.coord.lat;
                var coordLng            =   data.coord.lon;
                }
                }
                );

           }

           var x = 10000;
           var interval = setInterval(()=>{
                getCoordinates();
           },x);     

           ///.. don't forget to clear the interval when it's not necessary anymore
            clearInterval(interval);
```